# Función recursiva haciendo uso de return

Tags: haskell, return

Tengo importada la librería `Char` al archivo .hs

```
import Data.Char
```

También tengo esta función que pretende calcular y dar como resultado el mcd (máximo común divisor) de dos números pasados entre paréntesis.

```
mcd:: (Int, Int) -> Int 
mcd (x,y) = if isDigit(x) && isDigit(y) then
            if y == 0 then
               return x                  -- paso base
            else
               return mcd (y,(mod (x,y)) -- paso inductivo
```

Haskell está tirando error `return mcd (y,(mod (x,y))` y no sé si es un tema de paréntesis o de la coma.